# I want to use JQuery in Node.js and EJS but $ is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, npm, ejs

I want to use JQuery so I did like this.

1. npm install jquery
2. modify package.json

But it still doesn't work.

and this is .ejs page

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
<%
    $(".btn").click(function(){
        window.location.href = "/main";
    });
%>
</head>
<body>
    //display something
</body>
</html>
```

and this is app.js

```
var express = require('express');
var $ = require('jquery')(window);
var app = express();

app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.engine('ejs', require('ejs').renderFile);

var server = app.listen(8080);

app.use(express.static('public'));
app.use('/js', express.static(__dirname + '/node_modules/jquery/dist'));

var router = require("./routes/index.js")(app);
```

the error code is,

```
$ is not defined
```

how can I fix it?

Comment: did you try to change this <%%> with <script></script>

Comment: @husan yes, when I change, app didn't crash but still had a script error.

Comment: can you write error here

Comment: @husan

ReferenceError: /home/ubuntu/workspace/views/index.ejs:7

   5|         <script src="/js/jquery.min.js"></script>

   6|         <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">

>> 7|         <%

   8|             $(document).ready(function(){

   9|                 $(".btn").click(function(){
   10|                     window.location.href = "/main";

$ is not defined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am personally of the opinion that jQuery is best handled on the client side - it's better for your server's performance, otherwise you will have to work with the DOM on the server side - which will use more server resource.

However if you still want to use jQuery on the server side, then this link has a more complete guide:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/jQuery

Comment: I agree with you. I just want to use jQuery for some event like click, and animation. maybe I did like using jQuery on the server side.

Comment: you can easily do that by using a <script> tag in your ejs files - perhaps make the src a CDN of jquery - google hosted libraries. Doing it on the server side will just cause a lot of confusion in your code, and there is just no practical value for running jQuery on the server - it's 100% meant for client side.

Comment: Oh, god. you're right. now it works very well. thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're requiring the wrong file, since javascript is case sensitive.

You're requiring `jquery` when you want to be requiring `jQuery`. Try changing that.

Comment: Hm. What is the (window) parameter doing next to your require?

Comment: I just solved my problem with help of the man called mercy. thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

It did like this. node.js is so confusing. thank you so much.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
<script>
    $(".btn").click(function(){
        window.location.href = "/main";
    });
</script>
```